# How does a Bell measurement physically look like?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I do know how Bell states look like. They can be distinguished by doing a Bell measurement. A measurement has 4 possible outcomes (as there are 4 states, which form orthonormal basis). However I have no ideas how physically a Bell measurement looks like. 
How does a Bell measurement physically look like (as an experiment)?
A simple example would do fine.

Comment: Did you read the [section of the Wikipedia article on Bell's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem#Practical_experiments_testing_Bell.27s_theorem)=

Comment: @ACuriousMind :O I missed it! Though I didn't quite grasp how you differeniate between \11>+\00> and \11>-\00> states.

Comment: I don't think you have to differentiate these two states in the experiment - you just need to make sure that you start out with a |11>+|00> state.